# Mongodb need count for specific member id per day

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Collection name : activity
What I need is **activity count** 
of "memberId" = 123 
where activity "type" = 'xxx' 
per day 
between "11/01/2015" and "11/15/2015" // from date and to date range
Expected Output:
     [
       {date:"2015-02-22",count:10},
       {date:"2015-02-22",count:5},
    ]

I have no idea how to perform aggregate between dates and for a specific member id

where I am at is far far away from the solution :

```
db.activity.aggregate(
{ $project: {
    date: {
        years: {$year: '$dateInserted'},
        months: {$month: '$dateInserted'},
        days: {$dayOfMonth: '$dateInserted'},

    },
    memberId: '$memberId'
}},
{ $group: {

    _id: { memberId: '$memberId', date: '$date' },
    number: { $sum: 1}
}})
```

Comment: Can you [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33725131/edit) your question to include some sample documents and the expected output?

Comment: tried to create a dummy db on mongolab but mongolab is facing issues the collection structure is {memberId:1,item:"text",dateInserted:"2015-02-22 02:46:31.225Z"}, expected output is array of values, as in each day activity like [{date:"2015-02-22 02:46:31.225Z",count:10}] for charting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.activity.aggregate([ 
 {$match : { memberId : "xxx",item:"xyz",dateInserted: {$gte: ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: ISODate("2016-02-01T00:00:00.0Z")}}},
 {$project: {day: {day: {$dayOfMonth: '$dateInserted'}, month: {$month: '$dateInserted'}, year: {$year: '$dateInserted'}}}},
 {$group: { _id: { day: '$day' }, count: { $sum: 1} }},{ $sort:{_id:1}}
 ]);
```

Try that

Answer (score 0):

You may need add `$match` stage before `$project`:

```
    $match: 
    {dateInserted:{{$gte:new Date("2015-01-11T00:00:00 -02:00"),{$lte:new Date("2015-01-15T23:59:59 -02:00")}}},
    {memberId:123},
    {type:"xxx"}
```

Comment: the ROOT. isn't working for me and i dont see the member id and activity type problem addressed, http://www.screencast.com/t/1T2BObQgDedz

Comment: how about this: $match: {dateInserted:{
    {$gte:new Date("2015-01-11T00:00:00 -02:00")},
    {$lte:new Date("2015-01-15T23:59:59 -02:00")}
    }},{memberId:123},{type:"xxx"}

Comment: 'db.activity.aggregate(
    [ { $match : { memberId : "xxx",item:"text",dateInserted: {$gte:new Date("2015-11-01T00:00:00 -02:00"), $lte:new Date("2015-11-15T23:59:59 -02:00")}}} ]
);' not working